# Redirection in case of validation

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a simple redirection to another webpage, after a user successfully filled out a form

HTML (should be correct):

```js
(function($) {
  window.fnames = new Array();
  window.ftypes = new Array();
  fnames[0] = 'EMAIL';
  ftypes[0] = 'email';
  fnames[1] = 'FNAME';
  ftypes[1] = 'text';
  fnames[2] = 'LNAME';
  ftypes[2] = 'text';
  fnames[3] = 'ADDRESS';
  ftypes[3] = 'address';
  fnames[4] = 'PHONE';
  ftypes[4] = 'phone';
  fnames[5] = 'MMERGE5';
  ftypes[5] = 'text';
  /*
   * Translated default messages for the $ validation plugin.
   * Locale: DE
   */
  $.extend($.validator.messages, {
    required: "Dieses Feld ist ein Pflichtfeld.",
    maxlength: $.validator.format("Geben Sie bitte maximal {0} Zeichen ein."),
    minlength: $.validator.format("Geben Sie bitte mindestens {0} Zeichen ein."),
    rangelength: $.validator.format("Geben Sie bitte mindestens {0} und maximal {1} Zeichen ein."),
    email: "Geben Sie bitte eine gültige E-Mail Adresse ein.",
    url: "Geben Sie bitte eine gültige URL ein.",
    date: "Bitte geben Sie ein gültiges Datum ein.",
    number: "Geben Sie bitte eine Nummer ein.",
    digits: "Geben Sie bitte nur Ziffern ein.",
    equalTo: "Bitte denselben Wert wiederholen.",
    range: $.validator.format("Geben Sie bitten einen Wert zwischen {0} und {1}."),
    max: $.validator.format("Geben Sie bitte einen Wert kleiner oder gleich {0} ein."),
    min: $.validator.format("Geben Sie bitte einen Wert größer oder gleich {0} ein."),
    creditcard: "Geben Sie bitte ein gültige Kreditkarten-Nummer ein."
  });
}(jQuery));
var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

```html
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form action="https://yousport.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=7528537aa61af35234d05ad48&amp;id=969772de72" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
      <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
      <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">E-Mail Adresse  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
     </label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-FNAME">Vorname </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-LNAME">Nachname </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group size1of2">
        <label for="mce-PHONE">Handynummer  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
     </label>
        <input type="text" name="PHONE" class="required" value="" id="mce-PHONE">
      </div>
      <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-MMERGE5">Bewerbungstext  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
     </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE5" class="required" id="mce-MMERGE5">
      </div>
      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_7528537aa61af35234d05ad48_969772de72" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
      <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Jetzt für kostenloses Stativset bewerben" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
```

(JavaScript) Now, I tried to implement a redirection with a simple if ... else ...

```js
var LNAME = docment.getElementById('mce-LNAME')


$("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").on("submit", function.e)
if (LNAME.validity.valid) {
  function Redirect() {
    window.location.replace("/bewerbungsbestaetigung.html");
  }
} else {
  e.preventdefault();
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: many mistakes and misunderstanding of the language rules I really invite you to learn more about `JavaScript`.

Comment: Hello, I just started learning JavaScript. Could you explain me, why it does not work? Thank you!

Comment: there's many syntax errors alongside with logic errors, that will take time to explain so I suggest you dig more into `JavaScript` then you'll spot the errors by yourself.

Comment: I'm afraid that this explanation would be too large for an SO question/answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try asking for a more specific problem (I'm also not sure what your actual question is... to debug your code?)

Comment: yes, could you please debug my code? no need for extensive explanations, I will do the research myself. I created a "thank you page" ("/bewerbungsbestaetigung.html") on which the user should be redirected upon successful completion of the form. Right now, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on what I understand. You have if statement and now you wish to load another page. To do that you can use `window.location = 'nextpage'`

```
var LNAME = docment.getElementById('mce-LNAME')


$("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").on("submit", function.e)
if (LNAME.validity.valid) {
  function Redirect() {
    window.location = "/nextPage.html";
  }
} else {
  e.preventdefault();
}
```

Comment: that will not work. Many syntax and semantic errors are present in your code. So either provide an applicable solution or post you opinion in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these:

```
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

or

```
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

It looks like you have used the latter. So either the URL is wrong, or the logic preceeding it needs re-evaluation...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```js
var LNAME = document.getElementById('mce-LNAME')


$("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").on("submit", function(e) {
  if (LNAME.value) {
    (function redirect() {
      window.location.href = './bewerbungsbestaetigung.html';
    })();
  } else {
    e.preventdefault();
  }
})
```

Comment: How are you checking for validation?

Comment: Basically, the user should be redirected upon successful completion of the form. So, I tried to figure it out exemplary for the last name: If there is ANY text in the last name field (input name = LNAME (see above)), then and only then the user should be redirected to my "thank you page" which is called bewerbungsbestaetigung.

Comment: I figured out how it works if the user clicks the submit button, but once I add the condition it does not work anymore

Comment: How about now? I've updated the code. Please check it and let me know if it works.

Comment: still not working :/ Could it be, that maybe the reference to the form is wrong?

Comment: window.onload=function() {
          document.getElementById("mc-embedded-subscribe-form").onsubmit=function() {
            window.location.replace("/anmeldebestaetigung.html");
            return false;
          }
        }

Comment: The code does not check validation, but at least, it redirects me to the next page...